# Is there a way to avoid the Featured tab in IOS App Store?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, preferences

When there is an update notification on AppStore and I click on it to install whatever is pending, I typically get taken to the Featured tab.  That's offensive!  Is there any way to avoid this annoying behavior?

iPhone 5 "classic", IOS 7.1.2.

Comment: "That's offensive!" made me laugh

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible (at least not currently). When the iOS App Store is opened, it will either open up the default page, which is the Featured tab, or the last viewed page, if it was previously recently opened.

Perhaps you can suggest that the Updates tab should become the default tab if there are any pending updates, on Apple's [iPhone feedback page](https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html). However, I know that people sometimes choose not to update apps for whatever reason, so constantly being brought to the updates page might offend them...